# Rotating a RotationTranslation Matrix?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Good day,

I have been given a $4\times 4$ homogenous $\text{RT}$ Matrix, that maps frame $C$ to $A$.

I am then tasked to rotate that frame $C$ around the $Z$ axis w.r.t. $B$, to give a new frame $B$.

In the soluton, it states something like this:

[image]

I can't understand why the solution is like this. Isn't it just a simple Rotation Matrix * by the $\text{ATC}$ Matrix. Why is there an inverse involved!

Answer (score 0):

You have to bring the frame back to it's origin before applying said rotation. Here is an image to explain it

[image]

As you can see, you need to bring your frame back to A from C, so you do the inverse. Then you rotate about its own Z axis. Then you bring it back to C. If you don't do the inverse, you'll end up rotating the object around A like a pendulum or an object at the edge of a spinning plate, you don't want that given your formulation